# Icon doesn't change when its props change

Tags: reactjs, icons

I want to change the icon from play to pause depend on his props.
on the console, the props are changed correctly but the icon doesn't
here's my code

```
class Video extends React.PureComponent{
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { video: "initial", icon: true };
    this.handlePlay = this.handlePlay.bind(this);
   }
   handlePlay() {
     this.setState({ icon:!this.state.icon });
     let state = this.state.video.paused;
     state
      ?this.state.video.play()
      :this.state.video.pause()

     }
    render(){
      return (
       <Play playPause={this.handlePlay} icon={this.state.icon} />
     )
   }



class Play extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.icon) // -> console true/false
    return (
      <div onClick={this.props.playPause}>
       {this.props.icon ?<i className="fa fa-play" /> :<i className="fa fa-pause" />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it should work as intended. Could you provide more context please?

Comment: Please create Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok 1 sec ill update more info

Comment: @eladBA everything seems to be working as intended when I ran your code https://codepen.io/justinrsmith/pen/NyQzwK

Comment: after a bit checking is seems the problem is with the Dom it stuck there
and even it I try to delete it it throw an error 
like ? <i className="fa fa-play" /> : 'none' this will throw an error
that its not a Dom node child